# ¿Why my CORS config in django is not working?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, heroku

I have my REST API settings in my production.py file. This REST API is uploaded to Heroku and uses `django-cors-headers` with the following configuration:

```py
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Third-Party apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'gunicorn',
    
    # Local apps
    'core',
    'users',
    'checkers',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'myapi.herokuapp.com'
)
```

The idea when putting myapi.herokuapp.com in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST is to see if making the request from `localhost` is rejected (it would be the right thing to do). But this is accepted which gives me to understand that CORS is not working well.

Answer (score 0):

before fetch the django rest_api, make sure you setup `django-cors-headers` in your backend `settings.py`. for more information take a look at this [link](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/).

`pip install django-cors-headers`

settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'your-server-IP-address'
)
```

```
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]
```

Comment: Make sure you've added the `cors-middleware` in your `settings.py` file.